# Gaussian deconvolution for rapidly decreasing functions.

Tags: convolution, gaussian, inverse-problems, deconvolution

Gaussian convolution with variance $v$ is defined as
$$
{\cal G}_v[f](x):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi v}}f(y) e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2v}}dx.
$$
Given a function $g$, does there exist a a bounded continuous function $f$ to satisfy
$${\cal G}_v[f]=g?$$
Of course, this problem is ill posed in general.
To seek a solution, I impose the condition of a **rapidly decreasing function** in the sense of Schwartz to the target function $g$.

I think that this function class is suitable to find a solution.

The following is the back ground of this inverse problem;

This problem is useful when independent Gaussian noises $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ with variance appear.
Assume that we can observe only the noisy information $X_1+Y_1, \ldots, X_n+Y_n$ and
we need to recover the value $\frac{1}{n} (f(X_1)+\cdots+f(X_n))$, not $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.
In this case, we can use $\frac{1}{n} (g(X_1+Y_1)+\cdots + g(X_n+Y_n) )$.
In this case, the error
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} (g(X_1+Y_1)+\cdots + g(X_n+Y_n) )- \frac{1}{n} (f(X_1)+\cdots+f(X_n)) 
\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
is evaluated by using the supnorm $\|f\|_{\infty}$ because of the following reasons;
When $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are fixed,
the variable $g(X_i+Y_i)-f(X_i)$ is independent of $g(X_{i'}+Y_{i'})-f(X_{i'})$.
The variable $g(X_i+Y_i)-f(X_i)$ has average $0$ and its variance is bounded by $\|f\|_{\infty}^2$.
Hence, the variance of (1) is bounded by $\frac{\|f\|_{\infty}^2}{n}$.

To consider this problem, I read the following paper.
The following paper gives a solution when we adopt L^2 norm as the error.
However, I want to use supremum norm.

S. Saitoh
Approximate real inversion formulas of the gaussian convolution
Applicable Analysis, 83:7, 727-733, DOI: 10.1080/00036810410001657198

Comment: The stated convolution also occurs as the general solution of the 1D heat equation (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Some_Green's_function_solutions_in_1D). As such, this inverse problem is equivalent to another: If I know the temperature profile at one time, can I determine the temperature profile at an earlier time?

Comment: (Perhaps not surprisingly, the problem is ill-posed in general. See the discussion here for instance: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb/backward2.pdf.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks. I do not know what is "the temperature profile ". Could you explain it?

Comment: In physical terms, it's whatever the temperature is at various points within the domain. In math terms, it's just $u(x,t)$ at some particular time $t$ where $u(x,t)$ is a solution of the heat equation. (Also, more details on ill-posedness of backwards heat equation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163230/why-is-this-problem-ill-posed).

Comment: @Semiclassical I know that this problem cannot be solved in general. Hence, I am asking the case when $g$  is a rapidly decreasing function in the sense of Schwartz.